# Using React fetch gives pyramid.exceptions.PredicateMismatch: The resource could not be found

Tags: reactjs, api, pyramid

I am writing a React web client that use a REST API to communicate to a Python Pyramid backend. Problem is that only the methods POST and GET works. All other give error on the server. Also I can only use the "Accept' header, all other give the same error:

pyramid.exceptions.PredicateMismatch: The resource could not be found.

It works fine from Android app, using CURL, using Postman, and REST API plugins in browser mode. But for the fetch command in React it do not work.

Server Side:

```
config.add_route('admin_language_api',    '/api/admin/language')
```

```
def allow_CORS(config, log):
    def add_cors_headers_response_callback(event):
        def cors_headers(_, response):
            response.headers.update({
                'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
                'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'POST,GET,DELETE,PUT,OPTIONS',
                'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Origin, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization',
                'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials': 'true',
                'Access-Control-Max-Age': '1728000'
            })
        event.request.add_response_callback(cors_headers)
    config.add_subscriber(add_cors_headers_response_callback, NewRequest)
```

```
@view_config(route_name='admin_language_api',
             request_method='DELETE',
             renderer='json')
# @auth.require_api_auth
def delete_language(request):
```

React side:

```
export async function PServLanguagePost(languageObj) {
    const data = await fetch('http://localhost:6543/api/admin/language', {
        method: 'DELETE',
        body: JSON.stringify(languageObj)
    });
    return await data.json();
}
```

Server ERROR:

```
2021-05-07 04:53:34,041 INFO  [pyramid_debugtoolbar:287][waitress-3] Squashed pyramid.exceptions.PredicateMismatch at http://localhost:6543/api/admin/language      
traceback url: http://localhost:6543/_debug_toolbar/31383138393039313238303136/exception
```

Pyramid dump:

request:
`<Request at 0x228d20ffca0 OPTIONS http://localhost:6543/api/admin/language>`

attr:
`{'environ': {'REMOTE_ADDR': '127.0.0.1', 'REMOTE_HOST': '127.0.0.1', 'REMOTE_PORT': '56013', 'REQUEST_METHOD': 'OPTIONS', 'SERVER_PORT': '6543', 'SERVER_NAME': 'waitress.invalid', 'SERVER_SOFTWARE': 'waitress', 'SERVER_PROTOCOL': 'HTTP/1.1', 'SCRIPT_NAME': '', 'PATH_INFO': '/api/admin/language', 'QUERY_STRING': '', 'wsgi.url_scheme': 'http', 'wsgi.version': (1, 0), 'wsgi.errors': <_io.TextIOWrapper name='<stderr>' mode='w' encoding='utf-8'>, 'wsgi.multithread': True, 'wsgi.multiprocess': False, 'wsgi.run_once': False, 'wsgi.input': <_io.BytesIO object at 0x00000228D35C7040>, 'wsgi.file_wrapper': <class 'waitress.buffers.ReadOnlyFileBasedBuffer'>, 'wsgi.input_terminated': True, 'HTTP_HOST': 'localhost:6543', 'HTTP_USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:88.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/88.0', 'HTTP_ACCEPT': '*/*', 'HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE': 'en-US,en;q=0.5', 'HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING': 'gzip, deflate', 'HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_METHOD': 'DELETE', 'HTTP_REFERER': 'http://localhost:3000/', 'HTTP_ORIGIN': 'http://localhost:3000', 'HTTP_CONNECTION': 'keep-alive', 'waitress.client_disconnected': <bound method HTTPChannel.check_client_disconnected of <waitress.channel.HTTPChannel connected 127.0.0.1:56013 at 0x228d33c93d0>>, 'webob._parsed_cookies': ({}, ''), 'CONTENT_LENGTH': '0', 'webob.is_body_seekable': True, 'webob._parsed_query_vars': (GET([]), ''), 'webob._cache_control': ('', <CacheControl ''>)}, 'registry': pyramid.registry.Registry({}), 'invoke_subrequest': <bound method Router.invoke_subrequest of <pyramid.router.Router object at 0x00000228D1D07610>>, 'pdtb_id': '32333734333436323130343634', 'finished_callbacks': collections.deque([]), '_headers': <webob.headers.EnvironHeaders object at 0x00000228D33C9B80>, 'pdtb_sqla_queries': [], 'request_iface': <InterfaceClass pyramid.request.admin_language_api_IRequest>, 'response_callbacks': collections.deque([]), 'matchdict': {}, 'matched_route': <pyramid.urldispatch.Route object at 0x00000228D358EA00>, 'root': <pyramid.traversal.DefaultRootFactory object at 0x00000228D33C9C10>, 'view_name': '', 'subpath': (), 'traversed': (), 'virtual_root': <pyramid.traversal.DefaultRootFactory object at 0x00000228D33C9C10>, 'virtual_root_path': (), 'locale_name': 'en', 'exception': <PredicateMismatch at 0x228d35d8160 404 Not Found>, 'exc_info': (<class 'pyramid.exceptions.PredicateMismatch'>, <PredicateMismatch at 0x228d35d8160 404 Not Found>, <traceback object at 0x00000228D3448C40>)}`

Comment: Your example is missing the view configuration and callable. Please include it and any decorator. It sounds like not all of the predicates in your view configuration are matched, which is one cause of the error message. See https://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/api/exceptions.html#pyramid.exceptions.PredicateMismatch

Comment: Added the view in the description above. I took away the auth decorator but still problem.   It works perfect for my Android client (Kotlin), Java/Sping client, Postman, Firefox Rest plugin (RESTer). Just React with Fetch or Axios do not work.

Comment: OK, the view config looks fine. You comment isolates the problem to your code with React with Fetch. I don't see a Content-Type header. Try inserting the following into `fetch()`: `headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },`.

Comment: If you turn on the `pyramid.debug_notfound = yes` setting in your ini file then the http response will note which predicates are failing to match which will help understand what is going on.

Comment: Attached the dump. I can see: ```PredicateMismatch at 0x228d35d8160 404 Not Found``` .  The only difference between it working OK and failing is POST (work) vs DELETE (fail).  The only header working is Accept, all other give same 404.